# Can I set Algolia to only use a subset of the records I sent for development?

Tags: algolia

Can I set Algolia to only use a subset of the records I sent there for a development?  I am running out of record space on my development indices.

Answer (score 1):

This something you cannot set in Algolia, but what you can implement in your application.

You can configure your application to send only a subset of data to Algolia so the number of records won't be that high.

More information about how to approach different dev environments you can find in the documentation:

- https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/multiple-environments/#introduction
- https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/accounts-billing/do-you-offer-any-discounts-for-development-staging-environments/#faq-section